# How can I Knife Project only selected polygons, rather than the whole object?

Tags: bezier-curves, knife-tool

So I'm trying to knife project a circle here

[image: i even tried selecting only the polygons]

See the circle? Well I'm trying to cut it into the blue part. But it'll cut it into the pink and green as well

[image: even without selecting the only polygons]

And even still, the circle doesn't even cut correctly. See?

All I want is that exact curve circle cut into the blue area, that's it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see cutting through the pink part, although it cuts the green one. The Knife Project uses current viewport point of view, so.. where do you look at the mesh from  while executing Knife Project ?

Comment: you can hide (H key) the parts you don't want to be cut. Alt+H to see them again.